# Android: wrong listener behaviour?

Tags: android, onclick, listener, gesture, swipe

I am starting with android development. I would like to do a calendar activity. I have an activity with it implements `OnGestureListener`, with methods like `onFling()`, in order to `detect swipe gestures`, and change the month of the calendar. This works fine.

After that, my calendar has several cells, one per day. I added to each cell a `onclick` listener, in order to add a event for this day. When I do this, my `gestureListener` stops working, and only click events on cell are captured, but swipe gestures dosen't work (`onFling()` method is never called). What can I do?

This is my code:

```
public class Calendar extends Activity implements OnGestureListener{ ...

//OnFling method that detects the swipe gesture
@Override
   public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
   {
       try {
           if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
               return false;
           // right to left swipe
           if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           else if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Swipe up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }  else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Swipe down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

         return true;
   }

//This is the method attached to each cell for onclick event
public void showDialog(View v){
    TextView dia = (TextView)v.findViewWithTag("dia");      
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DialogoCalendario.class);
    i.putExtra("dia",(String) dia.getText() );
    i.putExtra("mes",   ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbMes)).getText().toString());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Show your code and see the following link https://www.google.co.in/search?q=detect+swipe+gestures+android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: I updated my post with the code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like View where you are using `GestureListener` is loosing the focus when you are working with cell. Just try with `calendarCellView.clearFocus();` when you are done with cell.